Aligning Notes and Theorems in paracol with Custom Environments
I am creating instructional lessons using the paracol package to structure my document into two columns. The left column is for my text notes, while the right column contains theorems and proofs using a custom environment.
However, I'm having trouble aligning my notes with the corresponding theorems and proofs. I've tried using \vspace, but the alignment looks off and inconsistent. Is there a better approach or package I can use to ensure the notes and theorems align correctly across the two columns? Any suggestions or code examples would be greatly appreciated!

\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper, openany]{book}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=0.75in, left=0.75in, right=0.75in]{geometry} % Customize margins
\usepackage{setspace} % For line spacing
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25} 
\usepackage{titlesec}  % For formatting titles
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{mdframed}   
\usepackage{paracol}

\newlength{\titleboxwidth}

% Define a new command for chapter format
\newcommand{\customchapterstyle}[1]{%
    \begin{flushleft}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
            % Square box for chapter number
            \node[draw, rectangle, minimum size=2cm, align=center] (square) {\sffamily\Large\bfseries\thechapter}; 
            % Title box to the right
            \node[draw, rectangle, minimum width=15.3cm, minimum height=2cm, right=.4cm of square, align=center, ] (title) {\Large\sffamily\bfseries{#1}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{flushleft}
}

% Define custom formatting for chapters using titlesec
\titleformat{\chapter} % Apply to chapters
  [display] % Block layout style for chapter title
  {\filcenter} % Center the content
  {} % No automatic number (handled by tikz)
  {0pt} % No extra space between number and title
  {\customchapterstyle} % Call the custom chapter format
  [] % No additional actions after chapter title

% Remove the vertical space before chapters
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-45pt}{0pt}

% Redefine section commands to use sans-serif font
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\sffamily\large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}

%Theorem
\renewcommand{\thelem}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{lem}}
\newenvironment{theorem}[1][]{%
\refstepcounter{lem}%
\ifstrempty{#1}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={%
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
\node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=blue!20, minimum height=1cm, minimum width=\titleboxwidth]
{\sffamily Theorem~\thelem};}}
}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={%
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
\node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=blue!20, minimum height=1cm, minimum width=\titleboxwidth]
{\sffamily Theorem~\thelem:~#1};}}%
}%
\mdfsetup{innertopmargin=0pt,linecolor=blue!20,%
linewidth=2pt,topline=true,%
frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax
}
\begin{mdframed}[]\relax%
\label{#1}}{\end{mdframed}}

%Proof
\newenvironment{proof}[1][]{%
\ifstrempty{#1}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={%
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
\node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=red!20, minimum height=1cm, minimum width=\titleboxwidth]
{\sffamily Proof:};}}
}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={%
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
\node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=red!20]
{\strut Proof:~#1};}}%
}%
\mdfsetup{innertopmargin=0pt,linecolor=red!20,%
linewidth=2pt,topline=true,%
frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax
}
\begin{mdframed}[]\relax%
}{\qed\end{mdframed}}

%Example
\newenvironment{example}[1][]{%
\ifstrempty{#1}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={%
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
\node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=green!20, minimum height=1cm, minimum width=\titleboxwidth]
{\sffamily Example};}}
}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={%
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
\node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=red!20]
{\strut Proof:~#1};}}%
}%
\mdfsetup{innertopmargin=7pt,linecolor=white!20,%
linewidth=2pt,topline=true,%
frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax
}
\begin{mdframed}[]\relax%
}{\qed\end{mdframed}}

\setcolumnwidth{0.28\textwidth/0.25in, 0.7\textwidth}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\sffamily

\chapter{Chapter Title}
\vspace{-0.75cm}
\vspace{-0.25cm}
\section{Section Title}

\begin{paracol}{2}
   \switchcolumn[1]

    \begin{example}
        This is where I put my examples
    \end{example}

    \switchcolumn[0]* 
        Text to be aligned with the text within Theorem 1.1
    \switchcolumn

    \begin{theorem}
        Here I put the theorem.
    \end{theorem}

    \switchcolumn[0]* 
        Text to be aligned with the text within Proof.
    \switchcolumn
    
    \begin{proof}
        Suppose that the assumption.\\
        Therefore, here is the conclusion.
    \end{proof}

\end{paracol}

\end{document}



Welcome to TeX.SE! Just a suggestion: I think it would be more sensible to first address the errors in the document, and then work on the alignment. For me, this code generates 9 errors. Are you missing a package?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
